# insert and concatenate field and save in third field in table of mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with 4 fields. Form values are saved in table, i want to concatenate two fields and save in third fields. I need to insert data and at the same time concatenate the values to one column. I need to retrieve the 'id', 'abbr' and save in 3rd column. it will be 'abbr'00'id'. Please somebody help me with the query to run. id is an auto increment field.

```
 id   abbr   trans_id  
----------------------
10 |  mm   |   mm0010
15 |  ss   |   ss0015
20 |  ss   |   ss0020
```

Its for naming the PDF created by form. When i manually use $pdf-

> Output($row['abbr'].'00'.$row['id'].'.pdf','F')

It works fine but when i insert same 'abbr' in form the created PDF get replaced by new one.But mysql keeps the record with same field value. I dont know if there is any other solution..Plz help, developers...

Answer (score 2):

Use this SQL

```
UPDATE table 
SET thirdFieldName = CONCAT(firstFieldName, secondFieldName)
```

This is for MySQL. It will concat the first field value and the second field and update the third field with the value

For example:

```
+-----+------+----------+-------------+
| id  | abbr | trans_id | forth_field |
+-----+------+----------+-------------+
| 10  | mm   | mm0010   |             |
+-----+------+----------+-------------+

UPDATE table
SET forth_field = CONCAT(abbr, '00', id)

+-----+------+----------+-------------+
| id  | abbr | trans_id | forth_field |
+-----+------+----------+-------------+
| 10  | mm   | mm0010   | mm0010      |
+-----+------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: thanks,it works.But i could not solve my problem which is touse this field for naming the PDF document.Earlier wheni name it manually- $row['abbr'].'00'.$row['id'].'.pdf' it works but replaces previous PDF if 'abbr' is same. Now PDF is without any name but database has the new entry. Please help..